# RESTful service calls

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I am doing an android application which uses Magento as a back end processing system. Now i can display the products in XML format once the user clicks on the product image. Which restful service call do I have to make? Can anybody tell me the restful service calls so that my transaction in mobile will work completely?

Comment: Just so I am clear, are you trying to create an entire shopping experience using the REST api?   Including checkout, etc?

Comment: s i wanted to know which webservice call i have to do , so that my transaction gets completed using SOAP/REST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to more info on what Rest Api's are avialable:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-SalesOrders

I do not believe they have an API out of the box that places orders.  You are going to have to build some custom APIs if you want a complete shopping via the APIs.

Comment: thank u sir....

Comment: Sudhir, if this helped, please be sure to choose the checkbox to accept the answer.